# How accurate is the depiction of the KGB?

Tags: plot-explanation, historical-accuracy, commander-hamilton

The movie [*Commander Hamilton (orig.: Hamilton)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119249/) seems to be set roughly at the time it was produced (1998), due to its use of cell phones and Russia instead of the  Soviet Union, as well as the operation of the Anglo-Norwegian Steel Co. in Murmansk. But it also seems to present the KGB as an actively working institution, e.g. when it is said that

> Whether KGB likes it or not they have to help us.

or when Barabanov is presented to be an active KGB agent. Yet, I thought the KGB was officially closed in 1991. But maybe they are just talking casually about ex-KGB officers that still have more or less their previous functions or the inofficial situation in Murmansk is/was more vague.

So **what is the actual time frame the movie is supposed to be set and how historically accurate is the depiction of the KGB** and its interactions with the other institutions in the movie? Do the novels maybe give more insight into this or is this maybe to blame on a not too accurate adaptation of the novels' story into a more modern setting?

Comment: KGB was't closed but renamed into FSB with its foreign intelligence part split into a separate service SVR. It was normal to call them KGB informally at least until 2000.